# From .txt data give values to inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill some inputs when you load a page, using the data I have from a .txt file. This file has a list of numbers

```
1
2
3
```

Something like this. So I wanted to read this lines and put them in their corresponding input. Suggestions on how to do this??

I tried with this code, but maybe I have a mistake that I don't know about, I'm starting with javascript.

```
function loadvalues()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.OpenTextFile("E://Steelplanner/Demand_Routing/Pruebas/OrderBalancing_Masivos/ModificaFechaTope/DueDate/Datosactuales.txt", true);
var Ia5 = document.getElementById("Ia5sem");
var text = s.ReadLine();
Ia5.value = text;
```

Comment: Not really sure on what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain the problem a little better?

Comment: forget about activeX, look into `FileReader()`

Comment: In my job they want to see the data inputed last time, so I have a text file where I saved that info. What I'm trying to achieve now is to get that same data and put it in the input boxes so the user can see his last run.

Comment: @dandavis does it work on IE?? Because that's the only web browser I can use to make the test of the code. And if it works in IE it work in the system my company uses to see the screens I made.

Comment: i dunno does it? http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: Ok, then.. how do I use it on the html?? I'm really new doing this, sorry

Comment: How do I use the Filereader() if I'm gonna selected a specific file?? All the examples I see use an input for files, and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know why, but I just changed the name of the variables and made a slight change in the .OpenTextFile line and it worked.

```
function loadvalues()
{
var file = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var text = file.OpenTextFile("E:\\Steelplanner\\Demand_Routing\\Pruebas\\OrderBalancing_Masivos\\ModificaFechaTope\\DueDate\\Datosactuales.txt", 1,false);
var Ia5s = document.getElementById("Ia5sem");
Ia5s.value = text.ReadLine();
var Ia4s = document.getElementById("Ia4sem");
Ia4s.value = text.ReadLine();
text.close();
}
```

Anyways, I'm gonna check the FileReader() for future references and the script @Sarjan gave, maybe I can improve it, but I have other things to finish. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `file.ReadLine()` until document not completely read using `while` loop with `AtEndOfStream` of `file` variable.

Here is example you can refer: [ReadLine Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7se9d4f.aspx)

Don't forget to replace TextFile path to your own text file path

My text file contains same data as in your example

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
//specify the local path to Open and always add escape character else throw error for bad file name
var file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Users\\MY_USER\\Desktop\\txtfile.txt", 1);
var Ia5 = document.getElementById("Ia5sem");
while (!file.AtEndOfStream) {
    var r = file.ReadLine();
    Ia5.innerHTML = Ia5.innerHTML +  ("<br />" + r);
}
file.Close();
</script>
```

```html
<p id="Ia5sem">HI</p>
```

Comment: Now let's say I have like 32 other input boxes, I just adapt this code for each one of them? or there's another way to reduce the code?

Comment: You want to get data from file and show it into input box?

Comment: Yeah, that's why all the numbers are separated like that. I have 32 input box and 32 numbers listed, so I just wanted to get the first, put it in the first input and so on...

Comment: What I suggest is try by your self and if you stuck somewhere then ask a new question with detail else answer will be out of focus of current focus. The hint is search for `getElementByTagName` for input and using `for loop` of file, set file data to input